# Using TagHelpers in Area Views

Tags: asp.net-core, tag-helpers

I spent the last hour refactoring to use Areas, now all my Views don't seem to have function taghelpers :/

So this is what's in the Index.cshtml

```
       <div class="btn-group">
           <a asp-controller="Survey" asp-area="Admin" asp-action="Create" class="btn btn-primary">Create New</a>
       </div>
```

...and this is the rendered HTML :/

```
<div class="btn-group">
  <a asp-controller="Survey" asp-area="Admin" asp-action="Create" class="btn btn-primary">Create New</a>
</div>
```

Intellisense doesn't even show the asp- prefixes and syntax highlighting on the asp- attributes is also lost.

Other SO issues reference "asp-route-area" but that just renders out verbtim like the rest.

These all worked fine when they were in ~/Views/Name/Index.cshtml, move them out to ~/Areas/Name/Views/Name/ and nopers...

Any thoughts?
Steve

Comment: Do you have a `_ViewImports.cshtml` in `~/Areas/Name/Views/` folder? Probably it doesn't exist.

Answer (score 17, accepted):

According to official [docs](https://docs.asp.net/en/latest/mvc/views/tag-helpers/intro.html#addtaghelper-makes-tag-helpers-available):

> The @addTagHelper directive makes Tag Helpers available to the view.
>   In this case, the view file is Views/_ViewImports.cshtml, which by
>   default is inherited by all view files in the Views folder and
>   sub-directories; making Tag Helpers available. The code above uses the
>   wildcard syntax (“*”) to specify that all Tag Helpers in the specified
>   assembly (Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.TagHelpers) will be available to
>   every view file in the Views directory or sub-directory.

If you use one layout per area, to use built-in tag helpers you should add `_ViewImports.cshtml` in `~/Areas/Name/Views/` folder(If you use shared layout you don't need. See [MusicStore project](https://github.com/aspnet/MusicStore/tree/dev/samples/MusicStore/Areas/Admin/Views) for shared layout example).

I guess you used one layout per area and you didn't add `_ViewImports.cshtml` `~/Areas/Name/Views/`. Copy `/Views/_ViewImports.cshtml` into `~/Areas/Name/Views/`.

Comment: This works. but do you know how to apply this too all areas? Say I use the root Layout = "~/Views/Shared/_Layout.cshtml";

Comment: Hi, I was wondering how this would work in areas without copying the _ViewImports.cshtml file so I downloaded the demo. Turns out it doesn't work. The demo doesn't use tag helpers in the area, it uses HTMLHelpers, that's why it would seem it works. So with your _ViewStart.cshtml you always have to copy the _ViewImports.cshtml as well into your area. Kind of annoying but I haven't found another way. Or don't use tag helpers at all and go with HTMLHelpers. Which I almost like better anyway.

Answer (score 4):

As it turns out, adding the `_ViewImports.cshtml` file to the `Areas/` folder cascades the visibility of the file to all `Areas/{area}/views` within the folder.

So rather than:

```
-> Areas
--> Area1
----> Views
------> _ViewImports.cshtml
--> Area2
----> Views
------> _ViewImports.cshtml
```

We can just do:

```
-> Areas
--> Area1
--> Area2
--> _ViewImports.cshtml
```

Or more visually

[image: example file structure for _ViewImports in Areas]