# TagHelpers Not Functioning in New Area

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, asp.net-core-tag-helpers

I created a new area on a project to separate concerns. However, I just ran into a strange issue where the taghelpers aren't working correctly, not even constructing the correct URL at all.

The original issue was on this:

```
<a class="btn btn-secondary btn-block font-weight-bold text-light" role="button" asp-area="Retail" asp-controller="RateQuery" asp-action="RateQuery"
   asp-route-partyid="@proOne.ProPartyId">
    @postFou.FouName<br>
    @postFou.FouAddr<br>
    @postFou.FouTown
</a>
```

I tried testing a bit:

```
<a href="/Retail/RateQuery/RateQuery?partyid=123">Test Link</a><br />
<a asp-controller="Main" asp-action="Index">Test Link to Home</a>
```

So, "Test Link" works, but "Test Link to Home" does not.

in the rest of my project, the regular area, everything works fine. I did register the area in the routing. Was I supposed to add something specific for taghelpers in the new area?

the project is on framework netcoreapp3.1

EDIT:

This also does not work:

```
<a asp-area="Retail" asp-controller="Main" asp-action="Index">Test Link to Home2</a>
```

Also, my Startup.cs:

```
 app.UseEndpoints(endpoints =>
{
    // Area route
    endpoints.MapControllerRoute(
        name: "areas",
        pattern: "{area:exists}/{controller=Home}/{action=Index}/{id?}");

endpoints.MapControllerRoute(
    name: "default",
    pattern: "{controller=Home}/{action=Index}/{id?}");
endpoints.MapRazorPages();
```

Comment: Is Test Link to Home the MainController in New Area ?

Comment: It's a Controller in the new area. It should work as well. "RateQuery" is also a valid contoller in "Test Link"

Comment: Have you check [Areas in ASP.NET Core](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/mvc/controllers/areas?view=aspnetcore-3.1) ? Do you miss add Controllers with the `[Area]` attribute to associate the controller with the area ?

Comment: I have the [area] attribute in as well. I feel like there's an issue with the routing...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First off, I want to credit this post: [Using TagHelpers in Area Views](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39652557/using-taghelpers-in-area-views)

The question is different, but the answer is in fact the same.
You need to create a specific _ViewImport.cshtml file for each Area, in the Views folder.

It appears that it can have the same markup as the main _ViewImports file, especially in my case where the _Layout file I'm using for these area views is located in the main trunk of the project.

By adding this file, the taghelpers are functioning properly and rendering the correct url.

Answer (score 0):

Try to add `asp-area`

```
<a asp-area="your new area name" asp-controller="Main" asp-action="Index">Test Link to Home</a>
```

result:
[image]

Comment: Hi @Nick Fleetwood, any update? If my answer help you resolve your issue?
 If not, could you please follow up to let me know?

Comment: Yeah, I tried that. I edited the question to show that. I do have the area attribute in the controller as well. No luck. I did adjust the routing in Startup also